# android: why action bar is missing when part of unity app?

Tags: android, android-activity, unity-game-engine, android-actionbar, push-notification

I have a unity3d app that contains a custom activity inside a native plugin. The activity opens when a user taps on a special notification (in the notif. bar) when he is outside the app. Once he taps it, the activity opens BUT without an action bar showing the app icon and name. However, when I run the same native code inside a non-Unity3d app, the activity comes up with the expected action bar.

Why is the action bar missing when the same activity runs as part of a unity3d app and how to make it show?

My manifest contains the activity as a simple:

```
<activity android:name="com.test.MyActivity"/>
```

I tried adding the following code to my activity's onCreate, but it didn't change anything:

```
b = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
Log.d("tag", "Requesting action bar: " + (b ? "true" : "false"));
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
if (actionBar != null)
    actionBar.show();
else
    Log.d("tag", "action bar is null");
```

output is:

```
Requesting action bar: true
action bar is null
```

Is there anything I can do differently?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

found a solution, looks viable enough - adding the following to the activity in the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar
```